# How to terminate scanner in java when filling an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create an array with a max length of 20 that can accept any number in each spot so long as it's within that range, but i'm having trouble figuring it out.

```
for(int i=0; i< MAX; i++)
     {

           array[i] = input.nextDouble();

 }
```

This fills in the array but i MUST input the max number of inputs and cannot simply end on, for example 5 inputs. Is there any to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the scanner to check if there is an additional [appropriate] input with [`hasNextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble--):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX && input.hasNextDouble(); i++) {
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just so something like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter the number of inputs:");
double MAX=input.nextDouble();
double[] array=new double[(int)MAX];
for(int i=0; i< MAX; i++)
 {

       array[i] = input.nextDouble();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user for the MAX value. The code will look something like this  -

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the MAX value : ");
    int MAX = input.nextInt();
    double[] array = new double[MAX];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
}
}
```